# How to make parent ListView box size the same as it's largest child in a nested ListView?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, nested-lists

For the last couple of days I have been trying to make this work without any luck.

I have two ListViews, one inside the other (nested). I want the items in the parent ListView to have the same size as its largest ListView child.

Is this possible? If so how?

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, ListView expands to the maximum width available, so no dependency to the child size within the ListView. In other words, you have some contstraint outside the parent ListView and both will use this width

Comment: Yeah, no matter what I do I have to give it a fixed size. It won't wrap around its children. If I don't give it a size, I get errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Think out of the box!**
In some cases, you should write your own customized widget.
I wrote a widget that can help you fix this problem :

```dart
class CustomListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, int) sepratorBuilder;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, int) itemBuilder;
  final int itemCount;
  final Axis scrollDirection;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  CustomListView({
    @required this.children,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    this.scrollDirection = Axis.vertical,
    // You can add any other property that you want ...
  })  : assert(children != null),
        assert(padding != null),
        assert(scrollDirection != null),
        itemBuilder = null,
        itemCount = null,
        sepratorBuilder = null;

  CustomListView.builder({
    @required this.itemBuilder,
    @required this.itemCount,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    this.scrollDirection = Axis.vertical,
    // You can add any other property that you want ...
  })  : assert(itemBuilder != null),
        assert(itemCount != null && itemCount >= 0),
        assert(padding != null),
        assert(scrollDirection != null),
        children = List.generate(
          itemCount,
          (index) => Builder(builder: (context) => itemBuilder(context, index)),
        ),
        sepratorBuilder = null;

  CustomListView.seprated({
    @required this.itemBuilder,
    @required this.itemCount,
    @required this.sepratorBuilder,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    this.scrollDirection = Axis.vertical,
    // You can add any other property that you want ...
  })  : assert(itemBuilder != null),
        assert(itemCount != null && itemCount >= 0),
        assert(padding != null),
        assert(scrollDirection != null),
        assert(sepratorBuilder != null),
        children = List.generate(
          itemCount,
          (index) => Builder(
            builder: (context) => Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                itemBuilder(context, index),
                if (index < itemCount - 1) sepratorBuilder(context, index),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: scrollDirection == Axis.vertical
            ? Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: children,
              )
            : Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: children,
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this :

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) => Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: List.generate(
          3,
          (index) => Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            width: (Random().nextInt(50) + 50).toDouble(),
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(
                (0xFFFFFFFF * Random().nextDouble()).floor() | 0xFF0000FF,
              ),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.5)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: Center(
        child: CustomListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30),
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the output :

[image: Output]

If you enable debug paint you can see the width of the `CustomListView` is the exact same as its widest child :

[image: Output]

Comment: Brilliant! That's perfect, just what I wanted. I totally missed the `List.generate` function.

Comment: Can I add the default scroll behavior that happens with ListView when the user drags the scrollable part of the screen and it moves up or down even when the list is empty?

Comment: Yes you can, if you want a scroll physic you can set the physics property of the SingleChildScrollView widget. Otherwise if you want to change the ScrollBehavior you can use the ScrollConfiguration widget as the parent of the SingleChildScrollView and set the behavior property of the ScrollConfiguration.